# How to use Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would simply like to use the functions from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) on my website.

I included this in the `<head>` section:

```html
<script scr="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

What else should I do? I tried to add:

```html
<script>
    var _ = require('lodash');
</script>
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: You don't need `require`. You use `_` directly. Since you've incuded the `js` file, you can use it like you do with jquery.

Comment: also  it's src not scr

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you load in Lodash using a script tag, the script will automatically expose the `_` function, and you can directly use it after including it in the document:

```js
document.querySelector("body").onload =
    function() {console.log(_.sample([1, 2, 3, 4]))}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

No need to require the function.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
```

Put these two lines of code in *head*, and you are ready to use Lodash in your JavaScript files.

Comment: not working. I want to use lodashjs in javascript file. I want to use compose function. Can someone help?